# Could not load type 'Android.OS.BaseBundle"

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin Android.
Without doing any changes to my project I'm getting this error:

```
UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
07-18 01:29:39.812 I/MonoDroid( 1901): System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Android.OS.BaseBundle' from assembly 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'.
07-18 01:29:39.812 I/MonoDroid( 1901): at Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.n_OnCreateView_Landroid_view_LayoutInflater_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x0009b>
07-18 01:29:39.812 I/MonoDroid( 1901): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.92b95183-96c6-4c05-8b2f-e6402eece616 (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x0003b>
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is pretty stupid.

In my visual studio solution I have multiple android projects.
Each project was set to compile for android 4.4.
After a rebuild the Xamarin tools decided to change the version of some projects to android 5.0.

Why? because Xamarin. That's why.

After reverting the version to android 4.4 everything worked!

Ho did I find it?
By chance. I saw that some files were modified (had a red SVN dot).

I hope this will save you hours if not days of "exciting and interesting work" :)